# Specify the X-axis range with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a histogram using `matplotlib`. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *


class Histogram(object):
    @staticmethod
    def plot_histogram(dictionary, labelx, labely, show, save, filename):  # x and y are list of values
        x = [int(year) for year,freq in dictionary.iteritems()]
        y = [int(freq) for year,freq in dictionary.iteritems()]
        print x,y
        plt.bar(x,y,align='center') # A bar chart
        plt.xlabel(labelx)
        plt.ylabel(labely)
        for i in range(len(y)):
            plt.hlines(y[i],0,x[i]) # Here you are drawing the horizontal lines
        if show:
            plt.show()
        if save:
            pylab.savefig(filename)


if __name__=="__main__":
    Histogram.plot_histogram({2015:1, 2014:1,2008:1, 2011:1, 2010:2, 2012:1},"x","y",True, False, "")
```

The output is:

[image]

The 6 years I'm interested in are constrained in one place. I need to stretch that area and display it properly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.axis()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis):

```
plt.axis([2010, 2016, 2, 0])
```

It takes this format:

```
axis([min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y])
```